# Find the value of an angle

Tags: geometry, triangles, angle

In an isoceles triangle ABC the angle ABC equals 135 degrees. The point F lies on AC. The angle ABF equals 90 degrees. AG is the bisector of the angle BAC, where G is the intersection point of BC and the bisector. How can I find the value of the angle GFC?

It's quite easy to find the angle A, but what shall I do next? I tried finding many angles, finding sums of the triangle's angles to find the value of GFC, but it was worthless.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's simple. If you calculate the various angles around vertex $B$ you realize that $BC$ is the exterior angle bisector of triangle $ABF$ through vertex $B$. Also, $AG$ is the angle bisector of $\angle\, BAC = \angle \, BAF$. Since the exterior angle bisectors of vertices $B$ and $F$ of triangle $ABF$ and the interior angle bisector of its vertex $A$ must intersect at a common point, that common point is $G = AG \cap BC$. Hence, $FG$ is the exterior angle bisector of $ABF$ through $F$. Thus, $$\angle \, GFC = \frac{1}{2} \,\angle BFC = \frac{1}{2} \,(\angle \, BAF + \angle \, ABF) = \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{45^{\circ}}{2} + 90^{\circ}\right)$$